# Google maps clustering not working, no pins are showing and there is no console error

Tags: typescript, google-maps, vuejs3

I have a new vue 3 project and I am using the google maps api to display custom pins and also use clustering as there are over 300+

Now this works consistently in dev and in staging with 200+ pins but live it does not work. No pins at all show on the map and no cluster markers.
There are no errors in the console and it just silently fails, I just have an empty map.

Here is my code for the map initialization, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
const loadResults = () => {
    loaded.value = false;
    ApiService.post("/widgets/"+props.id, {filter: filter.value}).then(({data}) => {
      widgetData.value = data.widgetData;
      mapData.value = data.mapData;

      //Load map via google api
      loader.load().then(async () => {

        var options = mapData.value.options;
        var locations = mapData.value.markers;

        // Request needed libraries.
        const { Map, InfoWindow } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps") as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
        const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker") as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;
        const { LatLng } = await loader.importLibrary("core");

        const map = new Map(
            document.getElementById("gmap") as HTMLElement,
            {
              zoom: options['scale'],
              center: {
                lat: options['lat'],
                lng: options['lng']
              },
              mapId: 'mapId',
              maxZoom: 25,
              minZoom: 4,
              disableDefaultUI: true,
              zoomControl: true,
              mapTypeControl: false,
              scaleControl: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              rotateControl: false,
              fullscreenControl: false,
            }
        );

        const infoWindow = new InfoWindow({
          content: "",
          disableAutoPan: true,
        });

        // Add some markers to the map.
        const markers = locations.map((location, i) => {

           var markerContent = document.createElement('div');

           if(location.app_logo!=undefined && location.app_logo!=null){
             markerContent.innerHTML = '<div class="logo"><img src="/'+location.company_guid+'/client/'+location.app_logo+'" /></div>';
           }
           else if(location.logo!=undefined && location.logo!=null) {
             markerContent.innerHTML = '<div class="logo"><img src="/'+location.logo+'" /></div>';
           } else {
             markerContent.innerHTML = '<div class="avatar-circle avatar-40px m-0"><p class="avatar-circle-inner">'+location.name[0]+'</p></div>';
           }

          const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
            position: new LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng)),
            content: markerContent,
          });

          // markers can only be keyboard focusable when they have click listeners
          // open info window when marker is clicked
          marker.addListener("click", () => {
            infoWindow.setContent(location.info_html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          return marker;
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        clusterer.value = new MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });

        //clusterer.value.setMap(map);

      });

      loaded.value = true;
    });
  }

    watch(() => filter.value, () => {
      loadResults();
    }, {deep: true})

    onMounted(() => {
      loadResults();
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone voted to close this question